# WebRTC video stream in local network not working after negotiation

Tags: javascript, c, webrtc, gstreamer

I am currently implementing a WebRTC connection between GStreamer and browser in order to stream a real-time video between GStreamer native-C application to the browser with some tweak in the signaling process and ran into some trouble.

In particular, the stream works nicely on localhost, however, when moving to WebRTC connection between GStreamer app and browser on different computers in the same local network, the SDP and ice negotiation work ok but the video stream is not displayed after ICE candidate negotiation is done.

I have tried other  [WebRTC connection implementation](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/tree/master/webrtc) and it works ok too,

Below is the SDP and ice information exchange on the browser, I have neglect unnecessary custom signaling format.

can somebody read the debug line below and take a diagnosis where I did wrong,

Thank you.

```html
DEBUG LINE OF NON-FUNTIONAL WEBRTC CONNECTION ON DIFFERENT MACHINE ON THE SAME LOCAL CONNECTION



[21:58:43] [signalling] "{\"sdp\":{\"type\":\"offer\",\"sdp\":\"v=0\\r\\no=- 4934955777944158885 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\ns=-\\r\\nt=0 0\\r\\na=ice-options:trickle\\r\\na=group:BUNDLE video0 audio1 application2\\r\\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96\\r\\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=setup:actpass\\r\\na=ice-ufrag:b2/RvzFNtQlz6g+6I/JR69Q0+QzHhLgM\\r\\na=ice-pwd:WcqIsQQrMLE6aS/rJmESAq3L5zKO8A+8\\r\\na=rtcp-mux\\r\\na=rtcp-rsize\\r\\na=sendrecv\\r\\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\\r\\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\\r\\na=framerate:120\\r\\na=ssrc:1125303830 msid:user2349809267@host-9af6f352 webrtctransceiver2\\r\\na=ssrc:1125303830 cname:user2349809267@host-9af6f352\\r\\na=mid:video0\\r\\na=fingerprint:sha-256 72:5C:71:66:5D:6A:15:94:E4:4F:D3:1A:93:1B:6B:31:53:AC:25:B2:7E:CF:43:C6:C7:43:E0:0B:81:3B:6B:33\\r\\nm=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 97\\r\\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=setup:actpass\\r\\na=ice-ufrag:b2/RvzFNtQlz6g+6I/JR69Q0+QzHhLgM\\r\\na=ice-pwd:WcqIsQQrMLE6aS/rJmESAq3L5zKO8A+8\\r\\na=bundle-only\\r\\na=rtcp-mux\\r\\na=rtcp-rsize\\r\\na=sendrecv\\r\\na=rtpmap:97 OPUS/48000/2\\r\\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli\\r\\na=fmtp:97 sprop-maxcapturerate=48000;sprop-stereo=0\\r\\na=ssrc:3829767784 msid:user2349809267@host-9af6f352 webrtctransceiver3\\r\\na=ssrc:3829767784 cname:user2349809267@host-9af6f352\\r\\na=mid:audio1\\r\\na=fingerprint:sha-256 72:5C:71:66:5D:6A:15:94:E4:4F:D3:1A:93:1B:6B:31:53:AC:25:B2:7E:CF:43:C6:C7:43:E0:0B:81:3B:6B:33\\r\\nm=application 0 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\\r\\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=setup:actpass\\r\\na=ice-ufrag:b2/RvzFNtQlz6g+6I/JR69Q0+QzHhLgM\\r\\na=ice-pwd:WcqIsQQrMLE6aS/rJmESAq3L5zKO8A+8\\r\\na=bundle-only\\r\\na=mid:application2\\r\\na=sctp-port:5000\\r\\na=fingerprint:sha-256 72:5C:71:66:5D:6A:15:94:E4:4F:D3:1A:93:1B:6B:31:53:AC:25:B2:7E:CF:43:C6:C7:43:E0:0B:81:3B:6B:33\\r\\n\"}}"

[21:58:43] [signalling] SDP{"sdp":{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 5000025825094643077 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE video0 audio1 application2\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:fngl\r\na=ice-pwd:XiGc1dyIIwTEW1k+02Wso5vL\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 5D:60:34:1F:24:76:6D:19:38:92:CB:44:31:38:11:A6:72:E8:74:89:CA:FF:96:49:D7:74:C1:02:FC:3C:24:E1\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:video0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 97\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:fngl\r\na=ice-pwd:XiGc1dyIIwTEW1k+02Wso5vL\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 5D:60:34:1F:24:76:6D:19:38:92:CB:44:31:38:11:A6:72:E8:74:89:CA:FF:96:49:D7:74:C1:02:FC:3C:24:E1\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:audio1\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:97 OPUS/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:97 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:fngl\r\na=ice-pwd:XiGc1dyIIwTEW1k+02Wso5vL\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 5D:60:34:1F:24:76:6D:19:38:92:CB:44:31:38:11:A6:72:E8:74:89:CA:FF:96:49:D7:74:C1:02:FC:3C:24:E1\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:application2\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\n"}}

[21:58:43] [signalling] ICE{"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:4278134664 1 udp 2113937151 07ad33a6-9166-4771-8fb7-3abf60b2e886.local 62190 typ host generation 0 ufrag fngl network-cost 999","sdpMid":"video0","sdpMLineIndex":0}}

[21:58:43] [signalling] ICE{"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:2773882820 1 udp 2113932031 352916bf-aeaa-4ad2-939c-d77fd1bf862f.local 62191 typ host generation 0 ufrag fngl network-cost 999","sdpMid":"video0","sdpMLineIndex":0}}

[21:58:43] [signalling] ICE{"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 14.248.228.58 62190 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag fngl network-cost 999","sdpMid":"video0","sdpMLineIndex":0}}





DEBUG LINE OF FUNCTIONAL WEBRTC CONNECTION ON LOCAL HOST



[15:4:12] [signalling] "{\"sdp\":{\"type\":\"offer\",\"sdp\":\"v=0\\r\\no=- 6210320772399984922 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\ns=-\\r\\nt=0 0\\r\\na=ice-options:trickle\\r\\na=group:BUNDLE video0 audio1 application2\\r\\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96\\r\\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=setup:actpass\\r\\na=ice-ufrag:ba8iIea3gwqQd3Tn/3JGfcDzZ4j/Ybat\\r\\na=ice-pwd:6hVfkFjMu9/cQQVJlJaiv41pEOVGf/8Z\\r\\na=rtcp-mux\\r\\na=rtcp-rsize\\r\\na=sendrecv\\r\\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\\r\\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\\r\\na=framerate:120\\r\\na=ssrc:602509614 msid:user211360764@host-fdaf0eba webrtctransceiver0\\r\\na=ssrc:602509614 cname:user211360764@host-fdaf0eba\\r\\na=mid:video0\\r\\na=fingerprint:sha-256 F1:40:E6:39:18:72:52:68:B0:55:84:EC:3C:AF:7B:53:63:A3:AC:3E:A5:8D:07:E3:E1:59:B9:2E:2F:51:26:83\\r\\nm=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 97\\r\\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=setup:actpass\\r\\na=ice-ufrag:ba8iIea3gwqQd3Tn/3JGfcDzZ4j/Ybat\\r\\na=ice-pwd:6hVfkFjMu9/cQQVJlJaiv41pEOVGf/8Z\\r\\na=bundle-only\\r\\na=rtcp-mux\\r\\na=rtcp-rsize\\r\\na=sendrecv\\r\\na=rtpmap:97 OPUS/48000/2\\r\\na=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli\\r\\na=fmtp:97 sprop-maxcapturerate=48000;sprop-stereo=0\\r\\na=ssrc:2552133861 msid:user211360764@host-fdaf0eba webrtctransceiver1\\r\\na=ssrc:2552133861 cname:user211360764@host-fdaf0eba\\r\\na=mid:audio1\\r\\na=fingerprint:sha-256 F1:40:E6:39:18:72:52:68:B0:55:84:EC:3C:AF:7B:53:63:A3:AC:3E:A5:8D:07:E3:E1:59:B9:2E:2F:51:26:83\\r\\nm=application 0 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\\r\\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\\r\\na=setup:actpass\\r\\na=ice-ufrag:ba8iIea3gwqQd3Tn/3JGfcDzZ4j/Ybat\\r\\na=ice-pwd:6hVfkFjMu9/cQQVJlJaiv41pEOVGf/8Z\\r\\na=bundle-only\\r\\na=mid:application2\\r\\na=sctp-port:5000\\r\\na=fingerprint:sha-256 F1:40:E6:39:18:72:52:68:B0:55:84:EC:3C:AF:7B:53:63:A3:AC:3E:A5:8D:07:E3:E1:59:B9:2E:2F:51:26:83\\r\\n\"}}"

[15:4:12] [signalling] {"sdp":{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 7732580003983207912 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE video0 audio1 application2\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:DlJ/\r\na=ice-pwd:YZT3FbfG71fRQBmuy69zIyZe\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 03:7A:4C:E2:4C:E5:EF:F3:B0:77:6B:52:03:A5:C9:13:0E:FB:B3:DC:67:AC:7A:E4:A4:76:42:E5:73:AD:DD:31\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:video0\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:96 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 97\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:DlJ/\r\na=ice-pwd:YZT3FbfG71fRQBmuy69zIyZe\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 03:7A:4C:E2:4C:E5:EF:F3:B0:77:6B:52:03:A5:C9:13:0E:FB:B3:DC:67:AC:7A:E4:A4:76:42:E5:73:AD:DD:31\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:audio1\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:97 OPUS/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:97 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:DlJ/\r\na=ice-pwd:YZT3FbfG71fRQBmuy69zIyZe\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 03:7A:4C:E2:4C:E5:EF:F3:B0:77:6B:52:03:A5:C9:13:0E:FB:B3:DC:67:AC:7A:E4:A4:76:42:E5:73:AD:DD:31\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:application2\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\n"}}

[15:4:12] [signalling] ICE{"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:2437072876 1 udp 2113937151 7eb508d4-4d95-4b82-81f3-1217cd0d9d26.local 59246 typ host generation 0 ufrag DlJ/ network-cost 999","sdpMid":"video0","sdpMLineIndex":0}}

[15:4:12] [signalling] ICE{"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 14.248.228.58 59246 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag DlJ/ network-cost 999","sdpMid":"video0","sdpMLineIndex":0}}




CONSOLE LOG OF FUNCTIONAL WEBRTC CONNECTION OF OTHER IMPLEMENTATION ON DIFFERENT MACHINE ON LOCAL NETWORK

Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:10 1 UDP 2015364607 172.29.144.1 50800 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:11 1 TCP 1015023103 172.29.144.1 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:12 1 TCP 1010828799 172.29.144.1 61886 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2015363326 192.168.1.2 50801 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1015021822 192.168.1.2 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1010827518 192.168.1.2 61887 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:4 2 UDP 2015363582 fe80::2c14:651e:2ca4:8176 50802 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:5 2 TCP 1015022078 fe80::2c14:651e:2ca4:8176 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:6 2 TCP 1010827774 fe80::2c14:651e:2ca4:8176 61888 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:7 2 UDP 2015364350 fe80::b98f:b224:f5d1:2f44 50803 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:8 2 TCP 1015022846 fe80::b98f:b224:f5d1:2f44 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:9 2 TCP 1010828542 fe80::b98f:b224:f5d1:2f44 61889 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:10 2 UDP 2015364606 172.29.144.1 50804 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:11 2 TCP 1015023102 172.29.144.1 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:12 2 TCP 1010828798 172.29.144.1 61890 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:13 1 UDP 1679819007 14.248.228.58 50797 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.2 rport 50797","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:14 1 TCP 847249663 14.248.228.58 9 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.2 rport 9 tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:15 1 TCP 843055359 14.248.228.58 61883 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.2 rport 61883 tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:13 2 UDP 1679819006 14.248.228.58 50801 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.2 rport 50801","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:14 2 TCP 847249662 14.248.228.58 9 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.2 rport 9 tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
webrtc.js:137 Received {"ice":{"candidate":"candidate:15 2 TCP 843055358 14.248.228.58 61887 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.2 rport 61887 tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
```